# Prove the function is periodic

Tags: definite-integrals, contest-math

If $f:[0, \infty) \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ is continuous so that:
$$
\int_{0}^{n} f(x)f(n-x)dx = \int_{0}^{n} (f(x))^2dx \quad \forall n\in \mathbb{N}^* \tag1
$$
then f is a periodic function.

**What I tried:**

Using substitution $x = ny$
$$
\int_{0}^{1} f(ny)f(n-ny)dy = \int_{0}^{1} (f(ny))^2dy \tag2
$$
then
$$
\int_{0}^{1} f(ny)(f(n-ny) - f(ny))dy = 0 \quad \forall n\in \mathbb{N}^*  \tag3
$$
which gives me the hint that the period might be $1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We immediately have
$$\int_0^n f(x)[f(x) - f(n - x)] \, dx=0$$
and, after making the substitution $x \mapsto n-x$, it follows that
$$
\int_0^n f(n-x)[f(x) - f(n - x)] \, dx=0
$$
Subtracting these two equations gives
$$\int_0^n [f(x)-f(n-x)]^2 \, dx = 0$$

Since $[f(x)-f(n-x)]^2$ is continuous and non-negative, it must be identically zero. So $f(x)=f(n-x)$ for all $x \in [0, n]$.

Now, fix $x$ and let $n=\lceil x+1 \rceil$. Then
$$f(x+1)=f(n-x-1)=f(n-1-(n-x-1))=f(x)$$
and so $1$ is a period of $f$.

Comment: Because $[a] <= a$, the number n - x - 1 is negative and f is not defined for negative numbers, so the last multi-equality cannot hold.

Comment: @EugenCovaci: $\lceil a \rceil$ is the smallest integer which is at least $a$, so $\lceil a \rceil \geq a$ by definition. Perhaps you are confusing it with $\lfloor a \rfloor$?

Comment: Well, it is now that I find out this conventions .Why not simply ceil(x) or floor(x)? Anyway, your prove is correct +1